# Give a name to timecapsule

Tags: domain-name, time-capsule

I have a timecapsule which is mounted on raspberry pi with ip address.

Badly, I have an electric problem and I have regularly electric cut. Everytime it happends, I need to change the ip address in raspberry.

I would like to add a name to my timecapsule and to set it to raspberry.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Apple Time Capsule already has a name, which it advertizes via Bonjour (also known as IETF ZeroConf, mDNS, etc). Install Avahi or mDNSResponder on your Raspberry Pi so it can make use of that.

Comment: My bad, I didn't know that. I had already install avahi on raspberry :/. Thanks :)